# Convert this js code to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JavaScript code from w3 schools which I like to convert to jQuery but i don't know how. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    var dropdown = $(".dropdown-section");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
      dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
          dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
        }
      });
```

Comment: Try and have look to the `.click`, the `.css`, `.toggleClass` and `.next` method

Comment: Hi, hanks for answering i done like this, and it's works but with this one all dropdown menu opens on click but i want to open only one that was clicked on. any sugestions?                                                                                    
$('.dropdown-section').on('click', function(){
    $(".dropdown-section").each(function() { 
    var dropdownContent = $(this).siblings();
    if(dropdownContent.css('display') === 'block') {
   dropdownContent.css('display', 'none');
   } else {
   dropdownContent.css('display', 'block');
   }
   });
});

Comment: Take an afternoon to read once through the [jquery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/). After that, the task will be a piece of cake to you and as a plus you will master similar challenges as well and you will have a grasp of idioms and API design motivations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code already contains jquery. It seems you want to remove `addEventListener` and check the css property .

For getting the next sibling use jquery `next` and to get the style use the `css` property

```
$(".dropdown-section").on('click',function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        let nextSibling = $(this).next()
        if(nextSibling.css('display')==='block'){
          nextSibling.style.display ="none";
        }
        else{
          nextSibling.style.display ="block";
        }
  });
```